Find $d_k$ that minimize $\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k\cdot\exp(-(d_1+\cdots+d_{k-1}))$

N.B.: The question has been edited after Sangchul Lee's answer to include an extra condition that is required for the original
problem to make sense.

Consider a strictly increasing sequence of strictly positive real numbers $d_k$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}d_k=+\infty$. I would like to find their values so that they minimize the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k\cdot e^{-(d_1+\cdots+d_{k-1})}.$$
I got to this while trying to solve a problem from Project Euler (so following the rules of that site, I cannot disclose more about it).
I tested some possible values out of intuition, but I'm not able to see a clear path that helps me finding out what should be the minimum.
Example 1: $d_k=\log(k+1)$. Then the series becomes $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log(k+1)}{k!}\simeq 1.55867$$
Example 2: $d_k=k\cdot\log(1+\varepsilon)$ with $\varepsilon>0$. Then the series takes the form $$\log(1+\varepsilon)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{(1+\varepsilon)^{k(k-1)/2}}.$$ Testing some values for $\varepsilon$ suggests that the series decreases as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$, but this would contradict the expected existence of a minimum for the total value of the series. In this particular example I'm not able to find a closed form either, but I suspect it may involve Jacobi theta functions.
Any hint on what strategy could be followed will be very welcome.

how about $d_k \rightarrow \infty$ or $d_k \rightarrow 0,, \forall k$?

@goldboy: I'm not sure I'm following what's your suggestion. The $d_k$ being strictly increasing and strictly positive is a condition of the problem, so it is definitely possible that they tend to $\infty$ but not to $0$.

There is no minimum of the series. The infimum of all possible values of the sum is $1$, which can be achieved by "letting $d_k \to 0^+$" and then noting that the corresponding "limit" is $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} , \mathrm{d}x=1$. (Indeed, the fact that the sum is always greater than $1$ can be easily proved by interpreting the sum as the sum of area of suitable rectangles.)

@SangchulLee, I still don't follow your argument. We cannot take $d_k\rightarrow 0^+$ because they are an increasing sequence.

What is meant is that you fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $d_k = \varepsilon$ (while not strictly increasing, this can be approximated by some strictly increasing sequences). Then the sum becomes $\varepsilon (1+ e^{-\varepsilon} + e^{-2\varepsilon} + \ldots) = \frac{\varepsilon}{1-e^{-\varepsilon}} \to 1$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Let me expand my comment as an answer.
1. Let $s_n = d_1 + \cdots + d_n$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-s_{k-1}} \cdot d_k
& > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{s_{k-1}}^{s_k} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= 1.
\end{align*}
So, the sum is strictly bounded below by $1$.
2. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $d_k = \varepsilon(1 - 2^{-k})$. The detail of this sequence is not important, except that $(d_k)$ is strictly increasing and bounded by $\varepsilon$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-s_{k-1}} \cdot d_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ e^{-s_k} \cdot d_k + (e^{-s_{k-1}} - e^{-s_k}) d_k \right] \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \int_{s_{k-1}}^{s_k} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x + (e^{-s_{k-1}} - e^{-s_k}) \varepsilon \right] \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x + \varepsilon \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
 (e^{-s_{k-1}} - e^{-s_k}) \\
&= 1 + \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
This tells that the sum can be made arbitrarily close to $1$. Summarizing,

The infimum of all such sums is exactly $1$, but

there is no $(d_k)$ achieving this infimum.



Addendum. Let $f(x) = \varepsilon x^2$. Also, set $s_k = f(k)$ and $d_k = s_k - s_{k-1}$. Then we observe that,

$f'(x) = 2\varepsilon x$ is increasing.

$d_k = \varepsilon (2k-1)$ is positive, strictly increasing, and unbounded.

For $k \geq 2$ and for any $x \in [k-1, k]$, we have
$$ d_k = \varepsilon(2k-1) \leq \frac{3\varepsilon}{2} (2k-2) \leq \frac{3\varepsilon x}{2}. $$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d_k e^{-s_k} \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x = 1$


Using these observations,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d_k e^{-s_{k-1}}
&= \underbrace{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d_k e^{-s_k} }_{\leq 1} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d_k [e^{-s_{k-1}} - e^{-s_k}]
\\
&\leq 1 + d_1 \underbrace{ (1 - e^{-d_1}) }_{\leq 1} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} d_k [e^{-s_{k-1}} - e^{-s_k}]
\\
&\leq 1 + d_1 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^{k} d_k e^{-f(x)} f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\\
&\leq 1 + \varepsilon + \frac{3\varepsilon}{2} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^{k} x e^{-f(x)} f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\\
&= 1 + \varepsilon + 3 \varepsilon^2 \int_{1}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\varepsilon x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
\\
&\leq 1 + \varepsilon + 3 \varepsilon^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\varepsilon x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
\\
&= 1 + \varepsilon + 3 \varepsilon \int_{0}^{\infty} t^2 e^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{$t = \sqrt{\varepsilon} x$}
\end{align*}
As $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, this converges to $1$. So, even if we restrict our attention to positive, strictly increasing, unbounded $(d_k)$, the set $\mathcal{V}$ of all possible values of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d_k e^{-s_{k-1}}$ satisfies
$$\mathcal{V} \subseteq (1, \infty]
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\inf \mathcal{V} = 1. $$
So, $\mathcal{V}$ has no minimum.

Wow, impressive insight! +1.

@SangchulLee Thank you, great answer! Thanks to point 2 in your answer and reviewing the Project Euler problem that originated my question I'm realising I should add the condition that not only the $d_k$ are increasing but also that they are unbounded. I will edit the question accordingly. If I get no answer for the new version in a few days, I will accept your current answer.

@A.Bellmunt, I added a proof that, even with such an extra restriction, the answer does not change.

Thanks, @SangchulLee! I now reviewed your addendum in detail and, although I think there are a couple of typos, they don't seem to affect the argument, so answer accepted. I will need to review my interpretation of the original problem because I must have missed something...
